# "Unreachable code" Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hi i try to make program who when will be compiled print X and Id arrays but i have a problem when i try add static int. I made this like on tutorial but it can't compile. Do you have any suggest?

```
class SetCord
{
   double x;
   double y;
   private  int Id;
   private static int NextId;

   public SetCord(double a, double b)
   {
      x=a;
      y=b;
   }

   public double getX()
   {
      return x;
      Id=NextId;
      NextId++;
   }

   public double getY()
   {
      return y;
      Id=NextId;
      NextId++;
   }

   public int getId()
   {
      return Id;
   }
}

class Test
{

   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
      SetCord[] teste = new SetCord[3];
      teste[0] = new SetCord(3, 5);
      teste[1] = new SetCord(5, 5);
      teste[2] = new SetCord(1, 2);

      for(SetCord x:teste)
      {
         System.out.println("give x" +  x.getX());
         System.out.println("give id" +  x.getId());
      }  
   }

   static
   {
      NextId=1;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'static
   {
      NextId=1;
   }' portion you can add on SetCord. It will help to solve your issue. You also need other tasks for getY and getX. That issue is already solved by others

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any statements post `return` in your method. `Return` should be the last statement of your method

**LIKE THIS:**

```
public double getX()
{
    Id=SetCord.NextId;
    SetCord.NextId++;
    return x;
}
public double getY()
{
    Id=SetCord.NextId;
    SetCord.NextId++;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now it's okey but, last error what i have with this http://pastebin.com/EJfDxJBp "nextId cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Updated my answer, do check :)

Answer (score 2):

Statements after `return` cannot be reachable. For ex

```
public double getY()
{
    return y;
    Id=NextId;
    NextId++;
}
```

What ever business logic you want to do, do before the method return. 
You want to do ?

```
public double getY()
{        
    Id=NextId;
    NextId++;
   return y;
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! Now it's okey, last error what i have with this http://pastebin.com/EJfDxJBp "nextId cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: `static
   {
      SetCord.NextId=1;
   }`